# How to "step into" function while debugging with multi line function call in PyCharm, without stepping through the individual argument lines?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I have a function call where the arguments are spread over several lines:

[image]

When I am on the line 133 and select "step into" during debugging, I would expect, that the debugger steps into the function `_include_default_entries` and I get to the corresponding source code file. However, it does not. It steps to the next line in the current file. I need to click "step into" several times until I actually step in the function body of the called function and navigate to the expected source code file.

=> Is this a PyCharm bug? Or is there some (hidden) configuration I could adapt to skip the arguments and immediately step into the function?

The settings I found so far do not seem to be related to this use case:

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-debugger-stepping.html#f0b05e75

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it could be a PyCharm bug. However, to achieve the desired debugging behavior, you can use the "step over" option, and then you will immediately enter the function body.

Comment: Does not work for me. Step over stays in the scope of the parent/current function (as expected) and does not jump into the called function.

Comment: No, step over will step over, not into the function.